# Referencing django.contrib.auth.login in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-contrib

I am new to Django and am having difficulty with using django.contrib.auth.login.

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myapp import views
from django.contrib import auth

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth.login)
)
```

Now, when I am trying to use the url in the template

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts/login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
```

I am  getting NoReverseMatch error.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

EDIT1:
I was finally able to resolve NoReverseMatch error. Thanks.
I still have a problem though. Here is my updated code:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from myapp import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),   
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login)
)
```

my template index.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
```

The issue:
When I get the page and click on "Login" I get the following error:

DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

So, it looks for the view in accounts/login/ and I do not have login view there, since
django.contrib.auth.views.login is supposed to provide me with the view.  How should I modify my urls.py? Or is there a different way to resolve it? Thanks.

EDIT 2:

my accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from accounts import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register')
)
```

Comment: if none of the recommended approaches work, try naming the url, and called the named url from the template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with this. Firstly, you're trying to call a non-view function in your urls. "auth.login" is the login function provided by the django auth app, but:

"auth.views.login" is the view function you want to be calling, so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

...
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login),
```

Whenever there's something wrong with one of your views, reverse will not work (I'll try to find the relevant piece of documentation on that).

Secondly, you're trying to reverse a URL path. Reverse will take the name of a view, or a URL name and return the URL for that. If you change your URLs to point to the view (as I mentioned above), akshar's answer should be correct:

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

Comment: That worked to get the page running, thanks! I still have another issue with this: django.contrib.auth.views.login is a view supposed to provide me with the basic login view and look for the template registration/login.html. When I map it onto r'^accounts/login/$' it is trying to find the view django.contrib.auth.views.login which I do not have there, since it is developed inside Django. So, when I click on the Login link, I get "DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/". How am I supposed to arrange it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. When you "map it", what is "it", and how / what are you mapping? Are you saying that you're getting a Template DoesNotExist error? Perhaps you could provide some code?

Comment: Hi Cazgp, I have just added the new code and described my issue inside the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a /login path inside accounts.urls? What's in that urls file?

Comment: No, there is no login path. I posted my accounts/urls.py inside the question,

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a TemplateDoesNotExist error. You need to create a folder in your templates folder called "registration", with a file inside called "login.html". Please read the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: You are correct and I did that. The template is in the registration/login.html. No, it is: " DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/ Site matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'pk': 1}".  In urls.py, I have url(r'^accounts/login/$', login), so it is trying to look there and I do not know how to get around it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31073/discussion-between-cazgp-and-gregory-r)

Answer (score 3):

You need to either use the urlname or the path to view when using `{% url %}.`

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth.views.login, name='account_login')
```

So, in template you can say:

```
<a href="{% url 'account_login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a
```

Comment: Thanks. I had actually tried the last option: <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a>, but it still gives NoReverse error. Somehow it can't find the view.

Comment: Can you try the first option

Comment: I have a different question, if you happen to know: django.contrib.auth.views.login is a view that has a basic login mechanism implemented. I can not know what its URL is, so why put anything about it in urls.py at all?

Answer (score 1):

Update for Django 2+

This works now:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
...
path('accounts/login/', LoginView, name='login'),
```

then you can use:

```
{% url 'login' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of functionality is built-in these days:

on *settings.py*

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/login'
```

on *urls.py*

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

then on django html templates, **for login**

```
href={% url 'login' %}
```

**for logout**

```
href={% url 'logout' %}
```